# Summing over rows containing particular strings in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataframe where the first column contains names of campaigns. I need to sum up all rows where the campaign names contain certain strings (it can appear in different places within the name, i.e. sometimes in the beginning sometimes in the end). The dataframe looks something like this:

```
    Campaign          Impressions    
1   Local display     1661246 
2   Local text        1029724 
3   National display  325832 
4   National Audio    498900 
5   Audio local        597339 
6   TV Regional        597339
...
```

So in this case I want to sum up all rows containing "local" in to one row, "national" into one, "regional" into one etc, like this:

```
    Campaign     Impressions    
1   Local        939293929
2   National     9232423423
2   Regional     1123123123
```

How can this be achieved? I've been trying with ddply without success....

Comment: Thanks. I used grep to rename the campaigns consistently, i.e.

```
    df[grep("Local", df$Campaign, ignore.case=TRUE),] <- "Local"
```
and then I just used ddply to sum over campaign names. This seemed easiest - got the idea from akrun's function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep` to find the rows that match the `Campaign` column categories ('Local', 'National', 'Regional') in a loop (`lapply`).  Subset the dataset ('df') based on `grep` and `sum` the 'Impressions' column and `rbind` the list elements.

```
res1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(c('Local', 'National', 'Regional'),
               function(x) {
         x1 <- df[grep(x, df$Campaign, ignore.case=TRUE),]
        data.frame(Campaign= x, Impressions=sum(x1$Impressions))}))
```

Or use `data.table`.  Keep only the 'Local', 'National', 'Region' in the 'Category' using `sub` and use that as "grouping" variable to sum the column 'Impressions'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Impressions=sum(Impressions)),by=
   list(Category=sub('.*?(Local|National|Region).*','\\U\\1', Campaign, 
   ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE))]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Campaign = c("Local display", "Local text", 
"National display", 
"National Audio", "Audio local", "TV Regional"), Impressions = 
c(1661246L, 1029724L, 325832L, 498900L, 597339L, 597339L)), .Names = 
c("Campaign", "Impressions"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the `grep` function : say your `data.frame` is called `mydata` then

> Local = grep(mydata$Campaign, pattern = "Local")
>
> National = grep(mydata$Campaign, pattern = "National")
>
> Regional = grep(mydata$Campaign, pattern = "Regional")
>
> mydata_sum = data.frame(Campaign = c("Local", "National", "Regional"), Impressions = c(sum(mydata$Impressions[Local]), sum(mydata$Impressions[National]), sum(mydata$Impressions[Regional])))

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

categories <- "Local|National|Regional"

mydf %>% 
  mutate(Campaign = tolower(str_extract((Campaign), ignore.case(categories)))) %>%
  group_by(Campaign) %>%
  summarise(sum(Impressions))
```

I needed to add the tolower, after extracting the strings, to make sure the group_by groups "local" together with "Local".